# C3P0: Not working when Jconnect4 driver used with Sybase

Tags: c3p0

We are trying to upgrade from jconn2 to jconn4 with Sybase 12.x version.
We are using c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar for connection and Preparedstatement pool.

When we use jconn4 we are getting below error

```
***com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: SQL Anywhere Error -685: Resource governor for 'prepared statements' exceeded
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.processEed(Tds.java:4003)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.tds.Tds.nextResult(Tds.java:3093)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(ResultGetter.java:78)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:289)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(SybStatement.java:271)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(SybStatement.java:2408)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(SybStatement.java:2394)
at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(SybPreparedStatement.java:257)***
```

We are setting below details in code.

```
ComboPooledDataSource cpds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
cpds.setDriverClass(jdbc_driver);    
cpds.setJdbcUrl(m_connURL);
cpds.setUser(m_username);
cpds.setPassword(m_password);
cpds.setMaxPoolSize(30);
cpds.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(10*60);
cpds.setPreferredTestQuery(m_connection_test);
cpds.setTestConnectionOnCheckin(true);
```

Could you please share why its not working with Jconn4 properly. Jconn4 is JDBC 4. Is that making any issue here. From the below link we could see that "As of version 0.9.5, c3p0 fully supports the jdbc4 spec."
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#what_is

Also when we use Jconn2 with same code,same DB settings and same C3P0 jar works fine. We are not getting any  Resource governor error.Please share your thoughts.

There are many places in our product where closing of PreparedStatement is left to C3P0. C3P0 takes care of closing statement when connection is released to Pool.

Comment: Same works with Jconn3 also.

Comment: Please see http://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/25804/sql-anywhere-error-685-resource-governor-for-prepared-statements-exceeded

Comment: Thanks Steve.. Our understanding is in our product There are many places  where closing of PreparedStatement is left to C3P0. C3P0 takes care of closing statement when connection is released to Pool.

Comment: C3P0 will close the prepardstements as we expected?

Comment: c3p0 will close uncached PreparedStatements when its parent Connection is closed. However, given that your database/JDBC driver enforces limits on open Statements, delaying PreparedStatement close until Connection close may take you closer to those limits. Post Java 7, it's very easy to clean up resource promptly using [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).